# Same vue function in react

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

How can i do the same create i did in Vue in React?

HTML Vue:

```
<h2>Add a Student</h2>
<a> Nome </a><input type="name" name="nome" v-model="aluno.nome" />
<button type="button" @click="addAluno(aluno)">Add Aluno</button>
```

Function Vue:

```
async addAluno() {
  let uri = "api/alunos";
  console.log(this.aluno)
  const response = await axios.post(uri, this.aluno).then((response) => {
    this.alunos.push({
      nome: this.aluno.nome,
    });
    this.aluno.nome = "";
  });
}
```

HTML React:

```
<Form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
    <h2>Add a Student</h2>
    <a> Nome </a>
<input type="name" name="nome" onChange={this.handleChange} />
    <button type="submit">Add Student</button>
</Form>
```

Function React:

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ aluno: event.target.value });
}

handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    await axios.post(url + "api/alunos/" + this.state.aluno)
        .then((response) => {
            this.alunos.push({
                nome: this.aluno.nome,
            });
            this.aluno.nome = "";
            this.getUsers();
        });
}
```

Whenever name i send i get an error("Guilherme" is the Input in this.state.nome):
POST http://127.0.0.1:8000/api/alunos/Guilherme 405 (Method Not Allowed).

Comment: hey ho, could you please also post what you already tried? 
Have you looked to the official documentation? there are already a lot of examples of how to fetch data on click on the web.

Comment: I post what i have tried so far and im looking for examples on the official documentation!!

Comment: It looks like you at least have the `submit`-handler making the request in React. The `405` error indicates your server (proxied via `/api`) isn't setup to accept `POST`.

Comment: Its weird because i use the same api in the vue function and works fine.. Its just one variable aluno-> nome :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is the way you using axios.

In vue you send:  axios.post(uri, this.aluno)
In react you send: axios.post(url + "api/alunos/" + this.state.aluno)

Your backend expect "aluno" as an object body, not part of your url. And axios expect 2 parameters on post function (as you did in vue). Try:

```
handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({ aluno: event.target.value });
}

handleSubmit = async (event) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    await axios.post(url + "api/alunos/", this.state.aluno)
        .then((response) => {
            this.alunos.push({
                nome: this.aluno.nome,
            });
            this.aluno.nome = "";
            this.getUsers();
        });
}
```

Thats it. ;)